# How to extract specific key/value during Http call in angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, http

Through a HTTP call I am having a JSON file like bellow:

```
[
    {
        "totalConfirmed": 555,
        "mainlandChina": 548,
        "otherLocations": 7,
        "deltaConfirmed": 555,
        "totalRecovered": 0,
        "confirmed": {
            "total": 555,
            "china": 548,
            "outsideChina": 7
        },
        "deaths": {
            "total": 17,
            "china": 17,
            "outsideChina": 0
        },
        "reportDate": "2020-01-22"
    },
    {
        "totalConfirmed": 654,
        "mainlandChina": 643,
        "otherLocations": 11,
        "deltaConfirmed": 99,
        "totalRecovered": 0,
        "confirmed": {
            "total": 654,
            "china": 643,
            "outsideChina": 11
        },
        "deaths": {
            "total": 18,
            "china": 18,
            "outsideChina": 0
        },
        "reportDate": "2020-01-23"
    }
]
```

from that, I want to store the value of `totalConfirmed, deaths & reportDate`. 
So my return would be something like this

```
{ 
   totalConfirmed : [555,654], 
   death: [17, 18], 
   dates: ["2020-01-22", "2020-01-23"]
}
```

Here is the function that I have written in my `service.ts`:

```
public filteredData(): Observable<History> {
let dataHistory: History;
return this.httpClient.get(this.hostURL).pipe(
  map(res => {       

    dataHistory.totalConfirmedPerDay.push(res["totalConfirmed"]);
    dataHistory.totalDeathPerDay.push(res["deaths"]["total"]);
    dataHistory.dates.push(res["reportDate"]);
    return dataHistory;
  })
);
```

}

and here is my History interface:

```
export interface History {
  totalConfirmedPerDay: any[];
  totalDeathPerDay: any[];
  dates: any[any];
}
```

But unfortunately, it's now working. I am having this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalConfirmedPerDay' of undefined
```

Comment: let dataHistory: History = {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do so using:

```
return this.httpClient.get(this.hostURL)
  .pipe(
    map(arr => {
      return arr.map(sub => {
        return {
          totalConfirmed: sub.totalConfirmed,
          totalDeathPerDay: sub.deaths.total,
          dates: sub.reportDate
        };
      });
    })
  )
```

now in the subscription block:

```
.subscribe(res => {
   let op: History = {
     totalConfirmedPerDay: [],
     totalDeathPerDay: [],
     dates: []
   };
   res.forEach(e => {
     op.totalConfirmedPerDay.push(e.totalConfirmedPerDay);
     op.totalDeathPerDay.push(e.totalDeathPerDay);
     op.dates.push(e.dates);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Typo mistake: `dataHistory` is not initialized.

```
public filteredData(): Observable<History> {
  return this.httpClient.get(this.hostURL).pipe(
    map(res => {
      return {
        totalConfirmedPerDay: res.totalConfirmed,
        totalDeathPerDay: res.deaths.total,
        dates: res.reportDate
      };
    })
  );
```

Comment: unfortunately, the solution u gave is not working. if you have time could u please check once with this link: https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily @xdeepakv

Answer (score 1):

The way to do map is

```
map((full:any[]) => {   //I don't want full    
   full.map(res=>{  //I want a "resumed" of full
     const obj={        //transform each element of full
       totalConfirmed:res.totalConfirmed,
       totalDeathPerDay:res.deaths.total,
       dates.res.reportDate
     }
     return obj; 
   )
   return full;
  })
```